# Handle double click in menu action in actionbar (-Sherlock)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Could I handle double click in menu options when them are in the ActionBar (from Sherlock) ?

or instead I have to change the default layout and use a custom layout?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

PS: If was possible access to views in actionbar (them are view too, right?) maybe I could handle what I would.